# How to remove a character using backspace on input field

Tags: javascript

I trying to make a input element that works both on mobile and web Chrome browser. Onkeypress works in Web Chrome but not in mobile Chrome browser.
So I used oninput that works on both.

I am concatenating a char say "-" to the input value after it exceeds 5 with the oninput event. After adding the '-' the backspace or delete key does not work. Also if cursor is moved in between the string and delete a char other than "-", it moves to the end of the string.

Please find my code below.

```
HTML
<input type="text" id="inputcheck" value='' oninput="getmeValidated(this, event);">

JAVASCRIPT
function getmeValidated(element, event){    
   if(element.value.length > 5){
      element.value = element.value+"-";
   }        
}
```

Comment: The backspace key does work, but `oninput` fires before the key is processed, so the length is still > 5, your code adds `-`, then the backspace keypress is processed and removes the `-` again, making it look like nothing happened. What's the point of adding the `-`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am actually using a "."  in place of -, it is for decimal input. Such that if user enters more than 3 digits, it should add a . I understood the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to only insert when the new value is longer than the old value, that way any delete action (be it backspace, select and cut, etc) would work as normal.

Also, input could be potentially be more than just a single character at a time. E.g. the user could do a copy+paste into the input field with a longer string. So instead of just adding the character to the end you could substring it in.

Here's a short snippet to demonstrate this (with comments to make it clearer):

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input')
let insertAt = 5
let charToInsert = '-'
let oldValue = input.value

input.addEventListener('input', (ev) => {
  let {value} = ev.target
  if (
    // Only insert when new value is longer than old
    value.length >= oldValue.length &&
    // Only insert when at correct length
    value.length >= insertAt &&
    // Only insert when it's not been inserted already
    value.charAt(insertAt) !== charToInsert
  ) {
    ev.target.value = (
      value.substr(0, insertAt) +
      charToInsert +
      value.substr(insertAt)
    )
  }
  oldValue = value
})
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

Answer (score 0):

Backspace is working but when you backspace with `-` added the `length` is already greater than `5` so it removes the last and adds new `-` due to your condition. You should have a `Boolean` to check if `-` is added yet or not

```js
let added = false;
function getmeValidated(element, event){    
   if(element.value.length === 5 && !added){
      element.value = element.value+"-";
   added = true;
   }
   if(element.value.length < 5) added = false;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputcheck" value='' oninput="getmeValidated(this, event);">
```

Comment: Good solution in principle, but if you delete the `-` it's never added again afterwards.